# Cannot find the difference between two type of iterate of two linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

> You are given two non-empty linked lists representing two non-negative
>   integers. The digits are stored in reverse order and each of their
>   nodes contain a single digit. Add the two numbers and return it as a
>   linked list.
>
> You may assume the two numbers do not contain any leading zero, except
>   the number 0 itself.
>
> Example:
>
> Input: (2 -> 4 -> 3) + (5 -> 6 -> 4) Output: 7 -> 0 -> 8 Explanation:
>   342 + 465 = 807.
>
> Following is the code I wrote:

```
ListNode dummy = new ListNode(0);
ListNode cur = dummy;
int add = 0;
while (r1 != null && r2 != null){
    int sum = r1.val + r2.val + add;
    add = sum / 10;
    cur.next = new ListNode(sum % 10);
    cur = cur.next;
    r1 = r1.next;
    r2 = r2.next;
}
if (r1 != null){
    int sum = r1.val + add;
    add = sum / 10;
    cur.next = new ListNode(sum % 10);
    cur = cur.next;
    r1 = r1.next;
}
if (r2 != null){
    int sum = r2.val + add;
    add = sum / 10;
    cur.next = new ListNode(sum % 10);
    cur = cur.next;
    r2 = r2.next;
}
if (add == 1){
    cur.next = new ListNode(1);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm, which could be described as follows, is correct:

1. Add elements of both lists while one of them does not run out,
2. Add any remaining "tail" elements from the first list,
3. Add any remaining "tail" elements from the second list,
4. Add "carry" if it is not zero/

Of steps 2 and 3, only one would be non-empty.

The problem with your implementation is the way you implemented 2 and 3: since you are using `if`, at most one element would be added, instead of processing the entire "tail".

Replacing `if` with `while` will fix this problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was fixed. I always get puzzled when stuck in a single problem for a long time.